# Como hacer un merge en un dataframe anidado en un dict

Tags: python

Cordial saludo. Intento realizar un merge con un geodataframe y un dataframe que estan cada uno dentro de un dict, pero siempre hay error al tratar de hacer merge dentro de un for porque espera un dataframe pero lee un dict, aun cuando trato de referenciar correctamente los valores del dict. Adjunto el codigo para hacerme entender mejor.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

grid = gpd.read_file("/home/kevin/Data/exercise-5/MetropAccess_YKR_grid_EurefFIN.shp")

lista = list(grid.YKR_ID)

YKRID = input("Enter YKRIDs:")          #Capturar entrada de usuario y almacenar en variable YKRID0 (5785640,5785641,5785642) 
5785640,5785641,5785642                 #valores digitados por el usuario a ser hallados
YKRID = YKRID.split(",")                #cambiar variable a tipo lista
YKRID = [eval(i) for i in YKRID]        #cambiar valores de lista a enteros
print("YKRIDs son: " + str(YKRID))      #mostrar valores ingresados por usuario

#------------------------------------------bucle para reportar si los valores estan en MetropAccess_YKR_grid_EurefFIN.shp-----------------------
for x in YKRID:                         
    if x in lista:
        print (str(x) + " is found" )
    else:
        print (str(x) + " Not Found")

#-------------------------------------------bucle para seleccionar y exportar cada codigo a un shp independiente---------------------------------
var_holder = {}

for x in YKRID:                         
    grid.loc[grid['YKR_ID']==x].to_file("/home/kevin/Data/exercise-5/Metrop_"+str(x)+".shp")
    var_holder['my_var_' + str(x)] = gpd.read_file("/home/kevin/Data/exercise-5/Metrop_"+str(x)+".shp")         # Leer cada shp a una variable 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
locals().update(var_holder)                               # Actualizar las llaves del dict ahora son variables accesibles por nombre
print(my_var_5785642)                                     # Ver alguno
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(var_holder))             # Mezclar todas las variables del {dict: var_holder} en una sola llamada "gdf" tipo geodataframe
gdf.to_file("/home/kevin/Data/exercise-5/Metrop_all.shp") # Convertir a .shp

#-----------------------------------bucle para leer como csv los txt solicitados por el usuario para almacenarlos en variable llamada "my_va_~"------------
var_holder1 = {}

for x in YKRID:                                                                 
    var_holder1['my_va_' + str(x)] = pd.read_csv(
        r"/home/kevin/Data/exercise-5/HelsinkiRegion_TravelTimeMatrix2013/" + 
        str(x)[0: 4] + "xxx/" + 
        "travel_times_to_ " + str(x) +".txt", sep=';') 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

locals().update(var_holder1)                               # Actualizar las llaves del dict ahora son variables accesibles por nombre

for x in var_holder1.values():                             # Agregar campo "YKR_ID" y llenar los valores del campo "to_id")
    x['YKR_ID']=x['to_id']


my_var_5785640.merge(my_va_5785640, on='YKR_ID')    # este es el merge hecho con el nombre de la variable pero debe hacerse para todos las variables y lo intento con el siguiente for:

for x in var_holder, var_holder1:
    var_holder[x].merge(var_holder1[x], on='YKR_ID')    # necesito realizar el merge pero no funciona dentro del for
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Desconozco lo que es un GeoDataFrame, pero estoy bastante seguro de que el bucle  `for x in var_holder, var_holder1:` no está haciendo lo que esperas. En la siguiente línea estás ejecutando `var_holder[x]`, por lo que creo que piensas que `x` es un entero de control en el bucle. Lo que quieres posiblemente sea `for x in range(len(var_holder)):`  o `for vh, vh1 in zip(var_holder, var_holder1)`

Answer (score 0):

Saludo a todos, gracias a la ayuda de https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/314917/jlgarcia pude resolver el problema con el siguiente for:

```
for vh, vh1 in zip(var_holder, var_holder1):
    var_holder[vh].merge(var_holder1[vh1], on='YKR_ID')
```